# How to see symbols of system libraries of android SDK, while debugging in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, android-ndk, symbols

I have ADT (Eclipse + ADT Plugin) + CDT + NDK + Android SDK.
I'm debugging an Android app using "Debug as"-->"Android Native Application" and it works ok, and loads my symbols, but only them.

How can I see the system function names (symbols) in the stack trace?

I got this from gdb:

```
warning: Could not load shared library symbols for 73 libraries, e.g. /system/bin/linker.
Use the "info sharedlibrary" command to see the complete listing.
Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?
warning: Unable to find dynamic linker breakpoint function.
GDB will retry eventurally.  Meanwhile, it is likely
that GDB is unable to debug shared library initializers
or resolve pending breakpoints after dlopen().
```

When executing `info sharedlibrary` the output is:

```
From        To          Syms Read   Shared Object Library
                        No          /system/bin/linker
0x400339b8  0x40062a38  Yes         /<path_to_my_local_folder>/mylib1.so
                        No          libstdc++.so
                        No          libm.so
                        No          liblog.so
                        No          libcutils.so
                        No          libgccdemangle.so
                        No          libcorkscrew.so
                        No          libz.so
                        No          libutils.so
                        No          libbinder.so
                        No          libemoji.so
                        No          libjpeg.so
                        No          libexpat.so
                        No          libstlport.so
                        No          libGLES_trace.so
                        No          libEGL.so
                        No          libGLESv2.so
                        No          libskia.so
                        No          libandroidfw.so
                        No          libnativehelper.so
                        No          libnetutils.so
                        No          libhardware.so
                        No          libsync.so
                        No          libui.so
                        No          libgui.so
                        No          libcamera_metadata.so
                        No          libcamera_client.so
                        No          libgabi++.so
                        No          libicuuc.so
                        No          libicui18n.so
                        No          libsqlite.so
                        No          libselinux.so
                        No          libdvm.so
                        No          libGLESv1_CM.so
                        No          libETC1.so
                        No          libwpa_client.so
                        No          libhardware_legacy.so
                        No          libsonivox.so
0x40997a38  0x40a05ac8  Yes         <path_to_my_local_folder>/mylib2.so
0x40a47ec0  0x40a5cca0  Yes         <path_to_my_local_folder>/mylib3.so
                        No          libstagefright_foundation.so
                        No          libspeexresampler.so
                        No          libaudioutils.so
                        No          libmedia.so
                        No          libusbhost.so
                        No          libharfbuzz_ng.so
                        No          libLLVM.so
                        No          libbcinfo.so
                        No          libbcc.so
                        No          libRS.so
                        No          libRScpp.so
                        No          libhwui.so
                        No          libandroid_runtime.so
                        No          libjavacore.so
                        No          libdrmframework.so
                        No          libdrmframework_jni.so
                        No          libstagefright_omx.so
                        No          libstagefright_yuv.so
                        No          libvorbisidec.so
                        No          libstagefright_enc_common.so
                        No          libstagefright_avc_common.so
                        No          libstagefright.so
                        No          libmtp.so
                        No          libexif.so
                        No          libstagefright_amrnb_common.so
                        No          libmedia_jni.so
                        No          libexif_jni.so
                        No          libsoundpool.so
                        No          librs_jni.so
                        No          libandroid.so
                        No          libchromium_net.so
                        No          libharfbuzz.so
                        No          libwebcore.so
0x4c715e90  0x4c778798  Yes         <path_to_my_local_folder>/mylib4.so
0x4c79459c  0x4c79c7dc  Yes         <path_to_my_local_folder>/mylib5.so
0x4c7af118  0x4c830994  Yes         <path_to_my_local_folder>/mylib6.so
0x4c905a50  0x4c989c10  Yes         <path_to_my_local_folder>/mylib7.so
                        No          libchromium.so
                        No          libstagefright_chromium_http.so
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No,  you cannot do that with a device that you don't have sources for. If you build your system from the source tree, you can have all symbols.